# Changing an image depending on the direction a character is heading - Pygame

Tags: python-3.x, image

```
import pygame
import os

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
GAME = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
FPS = 30
V = 5
LIMIT = pygame.Rect(WIDTH, 0, 1, HEIGHT)
CHARACTER_WIDTH, CHARACTER_HEIGHT = 35, 55
CHARACTER_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'character.png'))
BACKGROUND = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'background.png')), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
CHARACTER = pygame.transform.scale(CHARACTER_IMAGE, (CHARACTER_WIDTH, CHARACTER_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Escape Room - Game")


def draw_window(player):
    GAME.blit(BACKGROUND, (0, 0))
    GAME.blit(CHARACTER, (player.x, player.y))
    pygame.display.update()


def player_mechanical_movement(keys_pressed, player):
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and player.y - V > 0:  # Move Up
        player.y -= V
        pygame
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and player.y + V + player.height < HEIGHT:  # Move Down
        player.y += V
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and player.x - V > 0:  # Move Left
        player.x -= V
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and player.x + V + player.width < LIMIT.x:  # Move Right
        player.x += V


def main():
    player = pygame.Rect(450, 250, CHARACTER_WIDTH, CHARACTER_HEIGHT)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        player_mechanical_movement(keys_pressed, player)
        draw_window(player)
    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

That's my current code.
I want help to create a code that will make display of an image change when it moves in a different direction (In this case the image of a character of a RPG) so for example if I'm moving to my right, a selected image will display and if I change direction and go up, it will automatically change the image to an image of the character that is turning up.
Hope I explained myself clearly and I would really appreciate any help.
Thank you.